# Sort a stack in ascending order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, stack

Sort a stack in ascending order. You may only use one additional stack to hold items.

Any comments on my solution?
Worst case complexities:
Memory complexity: O(n)
Runtime complexity: O(n^2)

Also, I implemented the Stack class as having Object items and then cast these into Integers to be more general. Is this a good way of doing this?

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class Solution {
  // Sort a stack in ascending order
  // May only use one additional stack to hold items
  // Stack supports push, pop, peek, and isEmpty
  private Stack stack;

  private Stack auxiliaryStack;

  @Test
  void testStackIncreasingOrder() {
    stack = new Stack();
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(1);
    System.out.println("original stack");
    printStack();
    sortStack();
    System.out.println("Sorted stack");
    printStack();
  }

  @Test
  void testEmptyStack(){
    stack = new Stack();
    System.out.println("original stack");
    printStack();
    sortStack();
    System.out.println("Sorted stack");
    printStack();
  }

  @Test
  void testStackRandomOrder() {
    stack = new Stack();
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(12);
    stack.push(0);
    System.out.println("original stack");
    printStack();
    sortStack();
    System.out.println("Sorted stack");
    printStack();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution e = new Solution();
    System.out.println("Test reverse sorted stack");
    e.testStackIncreasingOrder();
    System.out.println("Test empty stack");
    e.testEmptyStack();
    System.out.println("Test randomly ordered stack");
    e.testStackRandomOrder();
  }

  public void sortStack() {
    auxiliaryStack = new Stack();
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      Object topOfStack = stack.pop();
      if (auxiliaryStack.top != null) {
        Object topOfAuxiliary = auxiliaryStack.peek();
        if ((Integer) topOfStack > (Integer) topOfAuxiliary) {
          emptyAuxiliary();
        }
      }
      auxiliaryStack.push(topOfStack);
    }
//    System.out.println("AuxiliaryStack");
//    printAuxiliaryStack();
    emptyAuxiliary();
  }

  public void emptyAuxiliary() {
    // Put all the elements of the auxiliary stack back in
    // the original one
    while (!auxiliaryStack.isEmpty()) {
      Object element = auxiliaryStack.pop();
      stack.push(element);
    }
  }

  public Stack getStack() {
    return stack;
  }

  public void printStack() {
    Node current = stack.top;
    while (current != null) {
      System.out.println(current.data);
      current = current.next;
    }
  }

  public void printAuxiliaryStack() {
    Node current = auxiliaryStack.top;
    while (current != null) {
      System.out.println(current.data);
      current = current.next;
    }
  }

}

class Stack {
  Node top;

  Object pop() {
    if (top != null) {
      Object item = top.data;
      top = top.next;
      return item;
    }
    return null;
  }

  void push(Object item) {
    Node t = new Node(item);
    t.next = top;
    top = t;
  }

  Object peek() {
    return top.data;
  }

  boolean isEmpty() {
    if (top == null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class Node {
  Object data;

  Node next;

  public Node(Object item) {
    data = item;
  }

  public Node(Object item, Node n) {
    data = item;
    next = n;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Generics

Generics... you want them. In your solution, they would be relatively easy to apply too. Consider your Node class:

> ```
> class Node {
>   Object data;
>
>   Node next;
>
>   public Node(Object item) {
>     data = item;
>   }
>
>   public Node(Object item, Node n) {
>     data = item;
>     next = n;
>   }
> }
> ```

Now, that Node only works on `Object` values, but you want it to be an `Integer`. Using generics, this is a treat (while we are at it, we will make `data` and `next` private and final, and add getters for them...):

```
class Node<T> {

  private final T data;
  private final Node<T> next;

  public Node(T item) {
    data = item;
  }

  public Node(T item, Node<T> n) {
    data = item;
    next = n;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

}
```

There, now Node is self contained, immutable, and generic. It can contain any object type, just specify the type you want when you construct it, for example:

```
Node<Integer> node = new Node<>(10);
```

Applying the same logic to your Stack class, we get:

```
class Stack<T> {
  Node<T> top;

  T pop() {
    if (top != null) {
      T item = top.getData();
      top = top.getNext();
      return item;
    }
    return null;
  }

  void push(T item) {
    Node t = new Node(item, top);
    // commented out, make Node immutable, pass in as constructor
    // t.next = top;
    top = t;
  }

  T peek() {
    return top.getData();
  }

  boolean isEmpty() {
    if (top == null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Right, that makes it generic, there are still a bunch of problems... but, it can be easy to use with:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
```

With the above stack, you should not need any casts from `Object` to `Integer`

### Simplifications

Now, looking at some other parts of your code, let's simplify...

Chained constructors: whenever possible, have just one constructor that "does stuff" for your class, and have your other constructors call the main one. Your constructors look like:

> ```
>   public Node(Object item) {
>     data = item;
>   }
>
>   public Node(Object item, Node n) {
>     data = item;
>     next = n;
>   }
> ```

Note that they both access the `data = item` item directly. It would be better to change your first constructor to be:

```
  public Node(T item) {
      this(item, null);
  }
```

The above constructor calls the second one with a null value.

Boolean expressions are boolean. If statements test a boolean condition. Why do both?

> ```
>   boolean isEmpty() {
>     if (top == null) {
>       return true;
>     }
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

This is a good one, it can be simply:

```
boolean isEmpty() {
  return top == null;
}
```

The push can be simplified too:

> ```
>   void push(T item) {
>     Node t = new Node(item, top);
>     // commented out, make Node immutable, pass in as constructor
>     // t.next = top;
>     top = t;
>   }
> ```

That can be simply:

```
  void push(T item) {
    top = new Node(item, top);
  }
```

Note that there is no need for the one-argument constructor now in the `Node` class.

Code duplication is always a red flag. Consider the following methods:

> ```
>   public void printStack() {
>     Node current = stack.top;
>     while (current != null) {
>       System.out.println(current.data);
>       current = current.next;
>     }
>   }
>
>   public void printAuxiliaryStack() {
>     Node current = auxiliaryStack.top;
>     while (current != null) {
>       System.out.println(current.data);
>       current = current.next;
>     }
>   }
> ```

Why have the method twice, when instead you can have just:

```
  public void printStack(Node<T> current) {
    while (current != null) {
      System.out.println(current.getData());
      current = current.getNext();
    }
  }
```

Now, you can call that method with either the `stack` or the `auxilliaryStack` top nodes... but, that method really belongs on the stack itself, not outside the stack. Move it to the stack, and it becomes:

```
  public void printStack() {
    Node<T> current = top;
    while (current != null) {
      System.out.println(current.getData());
      current = current.getNext();
    }
  }
```

Now you can simply do:

```
stack.printStack();
auxilliaryStack.printStack();
```

### Bugs

The following is a bug:

> ```
>   Object peek() {
>     return top.data;
>   }
> ```

What if the stack is empty? You will get a `NullPointerException`!

Instead, do:

```
  T peek() {
      return top == null ? null : top.getData();
  }
```

### Sorting

Your algorithm looks sane, but the interface is ... cumbersome. You have a `stack`, and `auxilliaryStack` declared as members of the `Solution` class. Now, the rules of object orientation indicate that the data should be encapsulated. There are two logical ways to implement the sort that I can see. The one is to have a static method that takes a Stack as input, and sorts it in place (creating a temporary, and method-private auxStack to sort with). The other solution adds the sort method to the Stack class itself (and also has an internal auxStack). The second route is the better one.

```
public void sort() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Stack<T> auxStack = new Stack<>();
    .....
}
```

I recommend you make the changes and see how it works out for you. You will find that the logic and flow of the structure is neater, and more manageable.